# How to return multiple values from a function.

Tags: java

This is more of a logical question than code specific, I have some twenty functions, each function calculates two values of my interest. However I can only return one value from a function. Now the other option I have is to make a class and implement setter and getter with global variables. I want to know if this is a feasible and recommended way? Or there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use global variables! Use some class that has your data as private fileds, and provide getters for it. Like in

```
class Pair<A,B> {
    final A one;
    final B two;
    public Pair(A fst, B snd) { one = fst; two = snd; }
    public A getFst() { return one; }
    public B getSnd() { return two; }
}
```

Then you can elsewhere say something like:

```
    return new Pair(42, "a result");
```

Comment: A better proposal for preserving multiple type.+1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Return a `Collection` from your function containing your values of interest.

Comment: An Array list you mean? That way I don't need to split it into two classes. Though I might be compelled to think about type safety.

Comment: Depends what you intent to return. If they are unique value you might use a Set or if they are key-value you might use a Map.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return a `List` or a `array`.

But if `return` types are different you can create custom class and use it as return type.

Example

```
public class Result {
   private String name;
   private int age;

  // getters and setters;   
}
```

Now you can have some thing like following

```
public static Result getInfo(){
    Result result=new Result();
    result.setName("name");
    result.setAge(10);
    return result;//now you can have String and int values return from the method
}
```

Comment: I think in my case the second option is preferred, my data types are very varied and a floating point difference can cause me problems.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the problem. But 2 solutions are :

1. Make new class which instances will be returned by all this functions. This class would have 2 attributes for each needed answer.
2. Return array or Collection with this 2 answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
long[] function() {
    long[] ret = { a, b };
    return ret;
}
```

or

```
long[] a = { 0 }, b = { 0 };

void function(long[] a, long[] b) {
    a[0] = ...
    b[0] = ...
```

or add properties to an object.

```
private long a,b;

void function() {
    a = ...
    b = ...
}
```

in the last case you can value.

```
class Results {
    public final long a;
    public final Date b; // note: Date is not immutable.
    // add constructor
}

public Results function() {
    long a = ...
    Date b = ...
    return new Results(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Type safety is an issue.

Comment: @user2822178 What are your calculated types?

Comment: I would like to discourage against #2, i.e. having the method affect the object's state. Of course it may be appropriate in certain contexts, but in general it should probably be avoided.

Comment: @Smallhacker I agree that all of them should be avoided, returning multiple values should be avoided.

Comment: @user2822178 all of these could be a `long` but I take your point that you want to check types.  In this case I suggest option 3 where you have a new object for each function.

Comment: @user2822178 I mean that instead of using a `Long` you might use a `long`, a `Date` is just a wrapper for a `long` and an `int` can be stored in a `long`.

Answer (score 1):

I think making a **Record** class is the most suitable.

```
public class Record {
    public final int a;
    public final int b;

    public Record(final int a, final int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Then your functions can return type `Record`, and you can access it with let's say `record.a` and `record.b`.

This is also one of the few cases where `public` variables and no getters and setters can be justified.

**UPDATE**: Implemented a proposed change, now everything is `final`, which means that `Record` cannot be modified when you get it back, which seems to be in line with expectations. You **only** want the results and use those.

Comment: I'd avoid the no-arg constructor and make the fields `final`, but otherwise a custom record is the cleanest solution...

Comment: @GyroGearless True, fixed it, that's indeed the case if all you want is to have two values returned.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways: collections, arrays ...
In my opinion the only way is to define a class with these values.
you do not need getter and setter methods if you don't need to regulate the visibility of the contents

```
class MyReturnValue {
  public int a;
  public int b;
}
```

in your code:

```
...
MyReturnValue result=new MyReturnValue();
result.a=5;
result.b=6;

return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to make a class and implement setter and getter with global variables rather than to Return Collection further it depends on your use.

Answer (score 1):

What about adopting `varargs` with generic helper function for getting around of number of returning variable limitation: In this solution, *we won't have to declare a new class every time when number of returning variable changes*.

```
class Results
{
    private final Object[] returnedObj;

    public Results(Object... returnedObj) 
    {
        this.returnedObj = returnedObj;
    }

    public <E> E getResult(int index)
    {
        return (E)returnedObj[index];
    }


}
```

**Test case:**

```
public static Results Test()
{
        return new Results(12, "ABCD EFG", 12.45);
             // or return larger number of value
}

//// And then returning the result

Results result = Test();
String x = result.<String>getResult(1);
System.out.println(x); // prints "ABCD EFG"
```

Comment: Great this solution!!

Answer (score 0):

You could even return the values separated by a special character say a "~" if you are sure that the "~" won't appear in your results.

Comment: An ugly hack - perhaps COBOL introduced records more than half a century ago!